# Install openssl-dev on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, openssl

In order to compile **NGinx** in need to install `openssl` and `openssl-dev` (I'am following a [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1849510865) guide).

So i'am doing this :

```
sudo apt-get install openssl openssl-dev
```

But i get an error telling me that it's impossible to find `openssl-dev`.
Also after some googling, it seems that `libssl-dev` is equal to `openssl-dev`, is that true ? (`apt-get` found `libssl-dev` on my server)

Here is my server version : 2.6.32-22-server

Any help welcome !

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If the likelihood that the dependencies for the version of a package that is in the release of Ubuntu (or other Debian derived arrangements) is the same as the deps for the version you are trying to build, you could run `apt-get build-dep nginx` or `aptitude build-dep nginx` - this will not install the nginx package but will instead install all those listed as dependencies (and their dependencies, as usual) which includes `libssl-dev` (the package that you are currently looking for).

In most cases this will allow the build of the other (presumably newer) version to be completed successfully, and it saves you installing each library and its header files one by one yourself. Even if there are new dependencies in the other version you are trying to build, `build-dep <package>` is a good place to start as it means that you only have to manually install the extra new dependencies.

As an example, the result on one of my servers is:

```
user@host:~$ sudo aptitude build-dep nginx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information
Initialising package states... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  autotools-dev cvs{a} debhelper gettext{a} html2text{a} intltool-debian{a}
  libcroco3{a} libmail-sendmail-perl{a} libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0{a}
  libssl-dev libsys-hostname-long-perl{a} po-debconf{a} zlib1g-dev
0 packages upgraded, 14 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
Need to get 7,217kB of archives. After unpacking 22.9MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?]
```

It is intending to install some libraries and headers, to enable an nginx build, but not nginx itself.

One thing to note is that if you are compiling your own copy because you want different build options rather than needing a different version for some reason, you may be better of compiling from the repository's source for the package rather than using the upstream sources directly. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130894/how-to-build-a-debian-ubuntu-package-from-source) is the first useful page that came out of a quick search, though you are likely to find more detailed tutorials easily if you need that.

<sub>An other small thing to note: the packages installed as a result of `apt-get build-dep` will be marked as manually installed as if you have done this by hand as you are currently doing. That means you can't remove them all in one go (there is no `apt-get unintall-dep` or similar) - though that is no different from the situation you'll get from manual library/header installs anyway (I only mention the fact as some people expect there to be a one-step way to undo a `build-dep` operation, and there is not).</sub>

Answer (score 153):

Yes, you are right. It is `libssl-dev`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imho.

Comment: Also usually with `libssl-dev` you have to install another related library `libcrypto-dev`, it is also a part of OpenSSL project.

Comment: This is still ok on Ubuntu 16.04. Cf https://serverfault.com/a/929084/568102 for more recent versions.

Answer (score 17):

Same problem on Ubuntu 18.04 in September 2018 and on Ubuntu 22.04.1 in January 2023

Resolved on Ubuntu 18.04 by doing:

```
sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev
```

It is unclear how to fix this on Ubuntu 22.04.1 for the time being

Comment: Had same issue, and sudo apt install libssl-dev; did not work. Tried this one, works fine. I expect that it depends on the particular program a person is trying to install which will require either `libssl1.0-dev` or `libssl-dev` (which is likely just the latest version, whereas the other one is 1.0 fixed)